# Create a UCMA 3.0 endpoint to a SIP PSTN gateway WITHOUT using Lync

Tags: sip, lync-2010, ucma

I want to use UCMA 3.0 (standalone, without Lync) to create an IVR application as modeled in the SDK docs:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg448007.aspx

I'd like a code snippet that demonstrates how to create the endpoint to a SIP PSTN Gateway so people can dial in from a regular phone and the app will pick up. I have the user name, password, and domain from the SIP provider. I could not find in any of the samples an actual code example of the model described in the link above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, the Visual Studio template included with UCMA already handles this (albeit in an ultra confusing way). If you create a new project and hit F5 it will start a standalone application listening on port 5060.

What it doesn't handle is SIP registration. For that you'll need to put a proxy server between your app and your provider. Check out http://www.brekeke.com/sip/, they offer a low-cost SIP server that can register against your SIP provider.